# Developer Story, import from GitHub: URL not correctly imported

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

When I import http://github.com/BiAtoms/Socket.swift through <kbd>Import from Github</kbd> in Developer story, the URL is imported as `http://github.com/BiAtoms/Socket`, dropping `.swift` at the end. However, the project name is correctly imported: `BiAtoms/Socket.swift`

Comment: I was able to repro this. Will pick this up as soon as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks very much for reporting this! There was a regex bug on our side that was chopping off characters that followed the period. This should be fixed now, so you can delete the broken story items and try re-importing your repos.